# How to show displayed db.query search results on same page in python

Tags: python, flask

I have a html page (searchCustomer.html), which has a input field, where we input the string to search in the database, the records are fetched successfully, after we click the search button and  are displayed in  html . I want to show the details of the record clicked from the html , when the first column (which is href) is clicked in the same page (searchCustomer.html)

```
<form action="/getsearchresults" method="post">
          <!-- <form action="/getsearchresults" method=  methods=['GET', 'POST'] > -->
          <Text  text="Customer Name" id="text0"/>
          <Input width="200px"  name="custName"  required  placeholder="Please enter the customer name"/>
          <button type="submit">Search Customer</button>
          <button  id="#btnID">TEst Customer</button>


</form>

<table border="1">
    <tr><td><strong>Customer Id</strong></td><td><strong>Name</strong></td></tr>
     {% for name1 in customers %}
     <tr><td><a href="/DispCustomerInfo?query={{ name1.name }}">{{name1.id}}</a></td><td>{{name1.name}} 
      </td></tr>
     {% endfor %}
</table>
```

on the click of the href,I want to display the details of that record in the same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution

```
from flask import request, jsonify

@app.route('/DispCustomerInfo')
def get_customer_info():
    name = request.args.get('query', False)
    customer = {}
    if name:
        #1 Query database
        #2 Assign result to customer
    return jsonify(customer)
```

On the front side use `Ajax` to get customer data.

```
<td><a class="customername" href="#" data-name="{{ name1.name }}">{{name1.id}}</a></td>
```

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".customername").on('click', function(){
       var name = $(this).data('name');
       $.get("/getReport", {'query': name}).done(function (data) {
           // Use jquery to append customer data to a DOM element.
       });
    });
});
```